# How to make google maps API get the restaurants in the specified area

Tags: asp.net, javascript, google-maps

So far I use http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=downtown&output=csv&key=whateverthekeyis to get the longitude and lattitude of some address.

```
function load() 
{
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
    { 
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('"mapHolderID'); 
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl()); 
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lattitude,longitude), 15); 
        var point=new GLatLng(lattitudelongitude);
        map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point);
    }
}
```

So if user enters Downtown it would take the user to downtown.
Now what I want is that if user searches for downtown resturants search result should point to downtown as well as list all the resturants in downtown.

Any Ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using version 2 of the google maps API, so you can probably integrate [LocalSearch](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#LocalSearch) pretty easily.  Should be as simple as calling *enableGoogleBar()* on your map instance.

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('"mapHolderID'); 
map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl()); 
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lattitude,longitude), 15); 
var point=new GLatLng(lattitudelongitude);
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point);
map.enableGoogleBar(); // <- new code
```